# Database Design - Struggling with a property that also needs to be an entity

Tags: database

Apologies if this isn't an appropriate place or question style, but I'm really struggling and hopeful I can get some help, even if it's just a pointer to another resource.  I've done some work with databases before and have been tasked with building a more complex structure.  There is one specific aspect of it I'm struggling to see how to model.

In short, I work at a school and a I need to build a database connecting students and TAs (teaching assistants) to classes.  On it's own I can build that...

Students would be entities with their obvious properties (ID, name, etc)
Classes would be entities (ID, name, periods they are on, etc)

This causes an N-N relationship so I'd have a linking table between the two.

So far so straightforward and I've build similar with an extension for teachers.

The problem with TAs (rather than teachers) is that they are assigned to periods of a class rather than whole classes.  So a student might have maths say every day period 1, assigning them to maths connects them to all of those lessons so the connection from the student to the class makes sense.

The thing is that a TA might only work in that class for Tuesday's period 1 lesson.  Now it's the periods that are the entities rather than classes, but the periods are a property of the classes.

I hope you can see my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice/guidance.

Comment: You'll have to break out the periods into another table.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't see how to do it.  The only approach I can think of would be to have a table (continuing the example from before) of MathsMon1, MathsTue1, MathsWed1 and so on, but also for the same for other subjects e.g. EngMon3, EngTue1, EngWed4 and so on.  This would be a huge table and time consuming to create as essentially it's just an expansion of the subject table.  I'm pretty confident this is where I'm going wrong and missing something...

Comment: Just link periods to classes and tutors to periods. Then a student in a class can see all their periods and tutors available in each one.